In C++, can I use std::set as a heap data structure?
With std::set, the time complexity of the operations:

insert(): O(log N)
erase(): O(log N)
begin(), which outputs the min value: O(1)
rbegin(), which outputs the max value: O(1)

Seems they have the same complexity requirement as a heap data structure.
So, can I use std::set as a heap data structure?

No. There is more to a structure than time complexity. A set and a heap are two totally different things.

Use std::vector and std::push_heap and friends.

Not unless it is defined to provide the same ordering semantics, which it isn't.

std::set and std::map are threaded binary trees.

The operations you call "insert" and "erase" do not refer to the same operations for a heap than than for std::set !!

The constant factors for std::set::insert and std::set::erase are significantly higher than those for priority_queue.

You have the question backwards. You are looking at time complexities, then asking if X can be used as Y. For the logic to flow in this direction, Y has to be defined in terms of time complexities, which a heap is not.
The defining property of a (max-)heap is that for every non-root node, the parent of that node is at least as large. The time complexities you know are corollaries of this definition, but they are not the definition. So, no, a std::set cannot be used as a heap because it does not satisfy the definition; it is not required to – and realistically does not – satisfy the heap property. (It could be used in place of a heap in many situations, but not as a heap.)
On the flip side, a std::set is defined (in part) by its time complexities. So it does make logical sense to flip your question and ask if a heap could be used as (an implementation of) a std::set. However, you still run into a "no" for various reasons, one of which is that a std::set must support a logarithmic find operation (and a heap does not).

First of all, as another answerer has already pointed out, a std::set does not allow duplicate elements, while a heap does, so a std::set doesn't satisfy all the requirements that a heap can. You have to use std::multiset.
But then you also have the fact that a heap can be constructed from N elements using O(N) comparisons, while a std::multiset will require O(N log N) comparisons in order to be constructed from an initial set of N elements assuming that most of the elements aren't duplicates. So in that sense std::multiset also can't provide the guarantees that a heap can.
Supposing that you don't care about this, yes, I suppose you could use a std::multiset as a priority queue, where *begin() gives you the smallest value, erase(begin()) removes the smallest value, and insert() adds an element to the priority queue. (That's not exactly the same as saying it's a heap. A heap is a concrete data structure. A priority queue is an abstract data structure, and can be implemented using any concrete data structure that provides the required operations.)

<joke>Me: Chef can I use a kettle to grill the beef? 
Gordon Ramsay: •••</joke>
You get the idea. std::set guarantees uniqueness among elements. This is not a requirement of a Heap data structure. Hence if you need a Heap and use an std::set, you could possibly lose millions of records because of that.
<joke>I can already hear "wtfs!" in code review.</joke>
I will feed you with your own logic and I think you will understand it immediately that way.
Since std::unordered_map, std::vector and std::array have O(1) in the average case for searching, can we use any of them we want?
